# MariaDB docker "Can't init tc log" when using mounted storage

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am initializing a new MariaDB database. Running docker with a volume to my home directory allows MariaDB to start up just fine:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name mymaria \
  -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp \
  -e MYSQL_USER=myapp \
  -v /home/myuser/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  mariadb:10.2
```

However, running the mariadb container with a volume via a mounted directory like so:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name mymaria \
  -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp \
  -e MYSQL_USER=myapp \
  -v /mnt/storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  mariadb:10.2
```

This configuration returns this from the `docker logs` output:

```
Initializing database
2019-09-23  5:12:13 139724696503616 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2019-09-23  5:12:13 139724696503616 [ERROR] Aborting


Installation of system tables failed!
...
```

**Simply removing `tc.log` as some folks have suggested does *not* work.** Restarting mariadb will rewrite `tc.log` back into the volume `/var/lib/mysql`.

Perhaps this is a permissions issue? I feel like I've tried every combination of `chown` with each directory.

I encounter this issue only with the `10.2` tag and not the `latest`. However, for an orchestration I'm working on, it suggests `mariadb:10.2`.

Comment: I previously posted this question in SuperUser and DBA. I've deleted those questions as this is probably the best place for this issue.

Comment: /mnt/storage/mysql what kind of storage is?

Comment: @c4f4t0r It's a mounted xfs drive connected via sata. Everything appears to get written to `/mnt/storage/mysql` by mariadb, until it hits the `tc.log` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

In my situation, I was using [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) to combine a variety of disks into a single file system. One of its features `direct_io` inhibits `mmap` and is likely what causes the fatal error. There are similar conflicts with other software that use `mmap` as pointed out by the [mergerfs documentation](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#plex-doesnt-work-with-mergerfs).

[Mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) is a used in MariaDB and is not supported by all filesystems. I believe in later versions mmap is no longer used, so in my own tests I only ran into this issue with `mariadb:10.2`.

This background may help others using `mergerfs` or with [similar issues causing conflicts with mmap](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185006/138340) in MariaDB.

## Possible Solutions

#### 1. Allow `mmap` to work

In my scenario this requires *disabling* a now deprecated feature called `direct_io` which bypasses page cache. According to the `mergerfs` documentation, [this is recommended](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#caching).

#### 2. [Activate Binary Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/activating-the-binary-log/)

This can be tested with [either a configuration file or as a command to the container's process](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/112). I tested this by adding the [--log-bin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#log_bin) command:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name mymaria \
  -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp \
  -e MYSQL_USER=myapp \
  -v /mnt/storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  mariadb:10.2 --log-bin --log-basename=some_hostname
```

#### 3. Move the volume elsewhere

While not ideal, this is an option. Either use a volume on the host or another disk. My particular issue with the MariaDB volume was because of a conflict between two different pieces of software.